# Inserting header logo in the bootstrap theme

Tags: logo

When you use an image as header logo(whichever size it is) in the bootstrap theme the img-responsive class will automatically resize the image.
But in wordpress theme, if you use large image for logo, it will occupy too much space in the page( I used 1475x 500 and It's occupying all the space in the page).
So how do I make the image to resize itself i.e., add class img-responsive to it (whichever styles logo takes using wordpress theme).

Answer (score 1):

Better method is to add only css code:

```
.custom-logo-link img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

But if you need to add a custom class to logo you can add a filter:

```
// Add custom class to logo.
add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', 'change_logo_class' );
function change_logo_class( $html ) {
    $html = str_replace( 'custom-logo-link', 'header-brand', $html );
    $html = str_replace( 'custom-logo', 'img-responsive', $html );

    return $html;
}
```